# How to make CKEditor multiline in ASP.NET webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

I already integrated CKeditor in my ASP.NET webforms by:

1. Implement dll: CkEditor.dll and CKEditor.NET.dll.
2. CKEditor folder containing all js, css and images.
3. In aspx page I include:

   ```
   <%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
   <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="ckEditorContent" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
   </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
   ```

Then I try to put default value into CKeditor using this code:

```
ckEditorContent.Text = "SampleText" + "\r\n" + "SampleText";
```

But the output won't break to a new line:

[image]

I also tried `Environment.NewLine`. It also doesn't work.

Comment: Wild guess: `<br>`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar <br> is working

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<pre>` HTML tag.

```
ckEditorContent.Text ="<pre>"+ "SampleText" + "<br/>" + "SampleText" + "</pre>";
```

or you can change config to add newlines.

```
config.protectedSource.push(/\n/g);
```

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-protectedSource